# Integrate using partial fractions

Tags: integration

Could you please help me solve this integral?

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}dx$$

### Revised

> $$\int\frac{1}{(x-3)(x-2)}dx=\int \frac{A}{x-3}+\frac{B}{x-2}dx$$

### Once undergoing the Partial Fraction Decomposition:

> $$A(x-2)+B(x-3)=1$$
> $$Ax-2A+Bx-3B=1$$
> $$(A+B)x+(-2A-3B)=1$$
> \begin{align}
> -2A-3B&=1 \\
> A+B &= 0 \\
> 2A+2B &= 0 \\
> -B &= 1 \\
> B &= -1 \\
> A &= 1 \\
> \end{align}

One can now say then:

> $$\int\frac{1}{x-3}+\frac{-1}{x-2}dx$$
> $$\ln\lvert x-3\rvert- \ln \vert x-2 \vert+C$$

Comment: **Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{x^2-5x+6} = \dfrac{1}{x-3}-\dfrac{1}{x-2}$

Comment: I guess by decomposing $\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}$ in partial fractions.

Comment: What do you know about partial fraction decomposition ?

Comment: alternativly one might complete the square in the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{1}{(x-2)(x-3)}=\frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-3}$. This is equivalent to

$1=A(x-3)+B(x-2)$. Letting $x=2$, we have $1=-A$ 0r $A=-1$, and letting $x=3$, we have $1=B$.\

Hence $$\int\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}dx=\int\bigg(\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-2}\bigg)dx=\ln|x-3|-\ln|x-2|+c$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6} = \frac{1}{(x-2)(x-3)} = \frac{A}{x-2}+\frac{B}{x-3}\cdots \cdots (1)$$

So $$\frac{1}{(x-2)(x-3)} = \frac{A(x-3)+B(x-2)}{(x-2)(x-3)}\Rightarrow 1= A(x-3)+B(x-2)$$

Now put $x=2$ and $x=3$ you will get $A$ and $B$ and put into $1$

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-5x+6=(x-3)(x-2)$, so $\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{(x-2)-(x-3)}{(x-2)(x-3)}=\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-2}$.

That can be easily integrated to get $ln(x-3)-ln(x-2)=ln(\frac{x-3}{x-2})$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-5x+6}dx$$

$$ = \int\frac{1}{x^2-3x-2x+6}dx$$

$$ = \int\frac{1}{x(x-3)-2(x-3)}dx$$

$$ = \int\frac{1}{(x-2)(x-3)}dx$$

$$ = \int\left(\frac{1}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-2}\right)dx$$

$$ = \log(x-3)-\log(x-2)+\log C$$

$$ = \log\Big(\frac{x-3}{x-2}\Big)+ \log C$$